# What happened to MS AJAX Library 4.0

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I started to use the ms ajax 4.0 client library during the beta stages(the client template bits) and since I have upgraded to vs 2010 rtm I wanted to update my ajax code as well but I can't find anything about the library in the official rtm bits. Has it been completely replaced by jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You will find what you need here http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AJAX&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

In addition to code poets response...

First things first. In previous releases, our Ajax framework was named ASP.NET AJAX. We now have changed the name of the framework to the Microsoft Ajax Library. There are two reasons behind this name change.....

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/10/21/the-microsoft-ajax-library-and-visual-studio-beta-2.aspx